# BackgroundWorker: Childs of Argument-Object

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I am working on a WPF Application that was running smooth until I added threadding. I wanted to ease the saving/autosaving process by putting it into a  `BackgroundWorker` so my UI is not blocked while saving occours.

Think of my App as a custom photobook maker.
Lets assume my UI consists of several Image Objects. The Source for those images lies within a custom `PhotobookImageObject` because each selected Image also contains additional Metadata.

**PhotobookImageObject**

```
public class PhotobookImageObject
{
    public BitmapSource source { get; set; }
    public String unimportantMetadata{ get; set; }       
}
```

When I want to save, I want to save the complete Photobook. For simplicity:

**Photobook**

```
public class Photobook: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<PhotobookImageObject> Photos{ get; set;}
        public String otherMetaData { get; set;}
    }
```

My Saving process worked when not using Threads. But ever since Im running it in a `BackgroundWorker` **I can not access the** `PhotobookImageObjects` in the `list` anymore.

Now I know the Thread for Saving can not Acces Objects from different Threads. This is why I am using a custom Class to Push the object into the thread of the BackgroundWorker. I found this solution here: [How do you pass a List<> of Lists<> to a background worker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64570217/how-do-you-pass-a-list-of-lists-to-a-background-worker)

**Here is the acutal code:**

Setting up the Worker:

```
private static BackgroundWorker saveWorker = new BackgroundWorker();


private static void saveWorkerExec(Photobook book, String Location, bool notAuto)
            {
                saveWorker.DoWork += doWork;
                saveWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                saveWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, o) =>
                {
                    Helper.Message("Photobook saved");
                    if (o.Error != null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("There was an error while saving! \n\n" + o.Error.ToString());
                    }
                };
                BGObj obj = new BGObj
                {
                    bk = book,
                    Loc = Location,
                    not = notAuto
                };
                saveWorker.RunWorkerAsync(obj);
            }
```

The custom class I use to transfer the Data:

```
 public class BGObj
        {
            public Photobook bk { get; set; }
            public String Loc { get; set; }
            public bool not { get; set; }
        }
```

And the actual part where the `BackgroundWorker` should receive the class into his own Thread:

```
    private static void doWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BGObj received = e.Argument as BGObj;
        Photobook book= received.bk;
        String Location = received.Loc;
        bool notAuto = received.not;
        
        //this function can not Access the books.Photos.last().source for example.
        SaveProjectToContainer(book, Location, notAuto);
    }
```

I am still receiving a System.`InvalidOperationException` when I try to access the `BitmapSource` of the `PhotobookImageObject` in the `Photos` List in `Photobook`.

My assumption: the `BGobj` I am creating is only **referencing** the actual Photobook so the data of its members is still resting in the wrong thread. How on earth can I make sure all submembers of my objects are actually passed to the Thread where I want to process them? Or am I wrong here and its something else?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When working with a `BackgroundWorker` (which btw is technologically obsolete, superseded by `Task.Run` and async/await), you are supposed to update the UI in the handler of the [`RunWorkerCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted) event. Have you tried this approach?

Comment: I am not updating anything in the UI. I want to pass all the required objects to the backgroundWorker and then I am serializing and saving all the information to file. No callback to the UI should be needed at any point.

Comment: OK. But you still need to return to the UI thread before being allowed to access the `BitmapSource` objects. The `RunWorkerCompleted` event runs on the UI thread, so you could take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody could help me with the issue I followed Theodors approach and switched to a more modern approach using `Async/Await`.

From my understanding this is not making the actions run in the background but still freeing the UI thread and running the `await`" tasks "inbetween" when the thread has capacity free. This allows me to access the UI-elements and still stop the application from freezin a bit while autosaving.

If someone needs a few hints how to solve this think of it like this:

```
public static void NotMain()
{
// queue following function. void Main for example would continue running after this.
await do_stuff_in_between(var object);
// Stuff after await will only happen if the function is done but UI is not blocked
Console.WriteLine("saving done");
}

public static async Task do_stuff_in_between(var object)
{
// do stuff with object or whatever you want.
}
```